# Converting .obj (3D files) to .tiff raster

Tags: raster, geotiff-tiff, dem, convert, obj

I have a 3D .OBJ file that i need to convert to raster (geotiff) so that i can use it in  QGIS/python gdal.

I have found several answers online about how to convert a DEM or TIFF to .obj, but not the other way around.

Does someone know how to convert .obj to .tiff?

Answer (score 0):

I found this one GitHub - it did exactly what I needed!

https://github.com/jeremybutlermaptek/mesh_to_geotiff

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).